# Button toggle to show drawer modal pop up react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, jsx, drawer

I a have added drag drawer modal by https://github.com/hanford/react-drag-drawer, and I am trying to set this button so that it toggles the drawer to show, that is done by changing the boolean state whenever its clicked.

you can see the drawer if you change  `<Drawer open={open}` to `<Drawer open={true}`, i want it to show by using the button onclick.

I've tried two different toggle functions the second one is in a comment, here is a code box snippet

https://codesandbox.io/embed/znmpllxk0m?fontsize=14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import Drawer from "react-drag-drawer";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { open: false };
  }

  toggle = () => {
    let { toggle } = this.state;

    this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
  };

  /* toggle = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        open: !prevState.open
      };
    });
  };
*/
  render() {
    const { open } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggle}>s</button>
        <Drawer
          open={this.state.open}
          onRequestClose={this.toggle}
          onDrag={() => {}}
          onOpen={() => {}}
          allowClose={true}
          modalElementClass="modal"
          containerElementClass="div"
          parentElement={document.body} // element to be appended to
          direction="bottom"
        >
          <div>Hey Im inside a drawer!</div>
        </Drawer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```